# How to creare .bbl file using Overleaf from references.bib?

Tags: overleaf, bbl

I am writing a manuscript for PLOS, and they need me to copy the references from .bbl file to the .tex file. Currently all my references are imported from mendeley in references.bib file in the same folder which consists of plos2015.bst and plos.tex. I have tried to keep citing and downloading the output.bbl file but those files have only the begin and end code, they don't get updated with the references in them to copy paste. Can someone help me with a step by step approach?

Answer (score 4):

As explained by Overleaf at [How do I download the automatically generated files (e.g. .bbl, .aux, .ind, .gls) for my project? My publisher asked me to include them in my submission](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_do_I_download_the_automatically_generated_files_(e.g._.bbl,_.aux,_.ind,_.gls)_for_my_project%3F_My_publisher_asked_me_to_include_them_in_my_submission)

> You can also download the .bbl file separately. Clicking on the "Logs and output files" icon next to "Recompile", then scroll right down to the bottom. Then click on "Other logs & output files"; you can then download the .bbl file.

Comment: I have tried to do that, but the output.bbl file generated is empty. It only has begin{} and end{} comments and no references between it.

Comment: @RohanAmare, I just tested on one of my overleaf projects and it did work. The downloaded .bbl file contains all the cited bib entries.

Comment: Can you try to use the Latex Template available on this website? 

https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/s/latex

I am using this template, and my issue is limited to only this journal. For other templates or projects, I am able to get the output.bbl file without any issues.
It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: @RohanAmare, the template does not contain a `.bib` file. The content of the corresponding `.bbl` file is already attached to the end of its `.tex` file.